# Aren't the value that useParams returns defined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Assume to use `useParams()` and access the correct values(path).
Aren't the value that `useParams` returns defined?

```js
// URL: /user/:userId, current URL is /user/100
const { userId } = useParams()
// userId is 100
```

But `userId`'s type is `string|undefined`. Why undefined?

This is my guess, `useParams()` just read URL string and parse it.
It does not have a separate cycle. It does not async, therefore, undefined type assumes a situation when the wrong path params are approached.

So I declare correct params, they aren't undefined.

Comment: Even if you are passing the correct params, it is highly possible that a user of yours hits the wrong route and reaches your component. React router dom cannot falsly guarantee you that `userId` would be defined, and hence it cannot let you access it safely. You can do your own magic around it using `as` etc, but that is it

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a route with no route path parameters, `path="/segment1/segment2"`, then the `useParams` hook will return an empty object with no route path parameters, e.g. where `userId` is undefined.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Component = () => {
  const { userId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ userId });
  }, [userId]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component</h1>
      <div>userId: {userId ? userId : "undefined"}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/user/100">User 100</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/segment1/segment2">Segment1 / Segment 2</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/user/:userId" element={<Component />} />
        <Route path="/segment1/segment2" element={<Component />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit arent-the-value-that-useparams-returns-undefined]

[image]

[image]

In Typescript you can cast the params if necessary:

```js
const { userId } = useParams() as { userId: string };
```